# MINIFS on several columns with blanc cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to apply MINIFS formula on 2 columns. Moreover, these columns can contain blank.

```
D2 =MINIFS(B:C;A:A;A2;B:C;"<>")
```

**Data**

```
ID | Date 1      | Date 2
1  | 02/05/2020  | 
1  |             | 10/08/2021
2  |             | 20/02/2021 
3  | 01/12/2019  | 10/12/2019
3  | 10/12/2019  | 
3  |             | 19/07/2020
```

**Expected Result**

```
ID | Date 1      | Date 2     | Result
1  | 02/05/2020  |            | 02/05/2020
1  |             | 10/08/2021 | 02/05/2020
2  |             | 20/02/2021 | 20/02/2021
3  | 01/12/2019  | 10/12/2019 | 01/12/2019
3  | 10/12/2019  |            | 01/12/2019
3  |             | 19/07/2020 | 01/12/2019
```

However, it is returning `#VALUE!`

Can you please explain me why? MINIFS doesnt support blank cells ?

Thank you

Comment: it is not the blank cells but the fact that you are using multiple columns with single columns.

Comment: From help "MINIFS will return a #VALUE error if a criteria range is not the same size as the min_range." Always worth looking at Excel help first.

Comment: Oh so `=MINIFS(B:C;...)` is not allowed ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use different size ranges in MINIFS.  So trying to use `B:C` with `A:A` will error.

I would use MIN with FILTER:

```
=MIN(FILTER(B:C,A:A=A2,""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much